# Conflict error 409 on WordPress that is using backend of Bluehost

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wpforms, http-status-code-409

Got issue that is occurring on two Contact Us page URLs. One is http://tangentconsulting.ca/contact-us/ and the other, also pointing to the same page, is tangentconsulting.ca/contact-tangent-consulting-services/ Both point to 409 Issue and give status "conflict". I talked with the Bluehost support person and they said my page is working fine. It is working fine but in Screaming Frog, I get conflict as a high Priority issue. I already deactivated and reactivated the plugins like wpforms, jetpack, jetpack boost, and redirection. Can you please break it down for me to help understand where this issue may originate from and some suggestions, so I can fix this?

We are trying to identify after getting audit by screaming frog and resolve the problems. I tries to ask the support persons, deactivated and reactivated the plugins, cleared the cache of browser, used different browsers, links are working fine but the crowling tool still mentioning this issue as a high priority. if there is any issue with these pages, i want to know the exact issue, if there isn't any, i want to clear this issue and after clearing, the crawler show it as resolved.